# php mixed associative array containing text and image

Tags: php

can you have a associative array containing text in the first element and a image in the 2nd.
How would you declare a array like that?

I have a function that I would like to generate a random piece of text.
Then it turns the text into a image.
I want to include both the text and Image in the return value (which i figured a array will work great).

below a random text string of 6 chars is turend into a image and sent back via header.
but I would like to send in back in a 2 element associative array.
Elm1 => random text
Elm2 => generated image

so its not a image file, but a generated image.

Sorry but Im very new to PHP

```
//Get each letter in one variable, we will format all letters different
$letter1=substr($rand_str,0,1);
$letter2=substr($rand_str,1,1);
$letter3=substr($rand_str,2,1);
$letter4=substr($rand_str,3,1);
$letter5=substr($rand_str,4,1);
$letter6=substr($rand_str,5,1);


//Creates an image from a png file. If you want to use gif or jpg images, just use the coresponding functions: imagecreatefromjpeg and imagecreatefromgif.
$image=imagecreatefrompng("./noise.png");
//$image = imagecreate(160, 45);

//Get a random angle for each letter to be rotated with.
$angle1 = rand(-20, 20);
$angle2 = rand(-20, 20);
$angle3 = rand(-20, 20);
$angle4 = rand(-20, 20);
$angle5 = rand(-20, 20);
$angle6 = rand(-20, 20);

//Get a random font. (In this examples, the fonts are located in "fonts" directory and named from 1.ttf to 10.ttf)
$font1 = rand(1, 12).".ttf";
$font2 = rand(1, 12).".ttf";
$font3 = rand(1, 12).".ttf";
$font4 = rand(1, 12).".ttf";
$font5 = rand(1, 12).".ttf";
$font6 = rand(1, 12).".ttf";

$colors[0]=array(0,0,0);
$colors[1]=array(0,0,0);
$colors[2]=array(0,0,0);
$colors[3]=array(0,0,0);
$colors[4]=array(0,0,0);
$colors[5]=array(0,0,0);
$colors[6]=array(0,0,0);



//Get a random color for each letter.
$color1=rand(0, 6);
$color2=rand(0, 6);
$color3=rand(0, 6);
$color4=rand(0, 6);
$color5=rand(0, 6);
$color6=rand(0, 6);

//Allocate colors for letters.
$bgColor = imagecolorallocate ($image, 255, 255, 255);
$textColor1 = imagecolorallocate ($image, $colors[$color1][0],$colors[$color1][1], $colors[$color1][2]);
$textColor2 = imagecolorallocate ($image, $colors[$color2][0],$colors[$color2][1], $colors[$color2][2]);
$textColor3 = imagecolorallocate ($image, $colors[$color3][0],$colors[$color3][1], $colors[$color3][2]);
$textColor4 = imagecolorallocate ($image, $colors[$color4][0],$colors[$color4][1], $colors[$color4][2]);
$textColor5 = imagecolorallocate ($image, $colors[$color5][0],$colors[$color5][1], $colors[$color5][2]);
$textColor6 = imagecolorallocate ($image, $colors[$color6][0],$colors[$color6][1], $colors[$color6][2]);

//Write text to the image using TrueType fonts.
$size = 15;

imagestring  ( $image  , rand(5,8)  , rand(5,15)  , rand(0,17)  , $letter1  , $textColor1 );
imagestring  ( $image  , rand(5,8)  , rand(30,40)  , rand(0,17)  , $letter2  , $textColor2 );
imagestring  ( $image  , rand(5,8)  , rand(55,65)  , rand(0,17)  , $letter3  , $textColor3 );
imagestring  ( $image  , rand(5,8)  , rand(80,90)  , rand(0,17)  , $letter4  , $textColor4 );
imagestring  ( $image  , rand(5,8)  , rand(105,115)  , rand(0,17)  , $letter5  , $textColor5 );
imagestring  ( $image  , rand(5,8)  , rand(130,140)  , rand(0,17)  , $letter6  , $textColor6 );

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
//Output image to browser
imagejpeg($image);
//Destroys the image
imagedestroy($image);
```

**Im not sure why I get marked down on this.**

Is this not what *stackoverflow* is for

( [**after some effort by one self**] **ask a question to get a answer from someone higher skilled**.)

Then you get some guy with who thinks in his oppinion that this is a silly questions and 'click' marked down. Come on admin (markdown reason).

Comment: what you mean by image in second element ?

Comment: How do you have "an image" in any variable in PHP in the first place...? And yes, that way would apply just fine to arrays as well.

Comment: You could use the name of the new image as the second element in the array like `$imgArray = array("name" => "bob", "image" => "images/bob.png")`

Comment: You can store an image as a base64 encoded string. In which case it will be a string, and you'll have an array containing strings.

Comment: Have you tried to return an array? Did it work?

Comment: at the bottom is a 'imagejpeg($image);'. I would like to store that in a element of a array along with the 'TEXT' in another element of the same array to return it. But how to include both in one array?

Comment: Im not sure why I get marked down on this. Is this not what the page is for ( [after some effort by one self] asking a question to get a answer from someone higher skilled.) Then you get some guy with who thinks in his oppinion that this is a silly questions and 'click' marked down. Come on admin (markdown reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the array, php doesn't really care what type a variable contains.

Instead of:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

just do:

```
$return = array(
  'text' => $rand_str,
  'image' => $image
);
return $return;
```

(assuming the code you posted is inside a function. Without knowing more on how you call the code it's hard to give a definite answer)

There is no need to output it to the browser.

Comment: Thank you Gerald. That was not hard was it. Not the solution but actualy helping somebody that did not know how to do something. This site has become so negative in recent times. Its a help site for people wanting to find out something, and a lot of experts are to critical. (excluding you now)